# EntityFramework contains not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
departments = (from p in _context.DateSnippets
                               where query.UserInfo.Departments.Contains(p.DepartmentId)
                               group p by p.DepartmentId
                                   into g
                                   select new Tuple<int, DateTime>(g.Key, g.Max(x => x.FromDate))
                               ).ToList();
```

I get the following exception for

> Contains() method

Here's the exception

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Only parameterless constructors and 
initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with Contains rather the issue is with your Select statement

Comment: try `p` instead of `p.DepartmentId`...

Comment: The issue is contains because if i take it off it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
new Tuple<int, DateTime>(g.Key, g.Max(x => x.FromDate)
```

Unfortunately when you execute this against database, it won't work because you can not pass parameters in constructors. one of the many workarounds could be using an object

```
new MyData {Key = g.Key, Date = g.Max(x => x.FromDate)}
```

Comment: You surely mean initializer syntax here (curly braces instead of round parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Contains` to an `Any`

```
where query.UserInfo.Departments.Any(d => d.DepartmentId == p.DepartmentId)
```

Change the Select to projecting to an annoymous class or poco. The error explicitly states you can not have parameters in the constructor

```
 select new 
 {
  g.Key,
  g.Max(x => x.FromDate)
 }
```

Comment: There is no d=>d in Entity framework for this use case

Comment: @eugenekgn, `d` represents your `department` entity

Comment: No it does not, not in the context